# Install4j Mac OS X installer dock name

Tags: install4j

I've noticed that in Mac OS X when I hover over my installer in the dock the tool tip says 'java' as opposed to having a more meaningful name (e.g.'MyApp Installer'). Is there anything can change in my configuration to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the installer calls the java launcher (the launchers don't do that). There are reasons for that, but I've created an issue to check whether we can change the displayed tool tip. I don't see any workaround that you could apply yourself.